# "Extend" highcharts chart add properties and functions, prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, highcharts

Another guy here trying to understand how to "extend" js "classes", functional objects.

Specifically i am using highcharts and need to add additional properties and some methods.

i am creating a chart like this:

```
var theChart = $('#chartDiv').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            plotBorderColor: '#2d2d30',
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#1e1e1e',
            marginTop: 2,
            animation: true,
            spacingBottom: 0,
            spacingTop: 10,
            ..........................

         });
 var chart = $('#chartDiv').highcharts();
```

So where and how exactly would i add additional properties so the final 'chart' object would have them? I guess as a first or second question is why wouldn't the 'theChart' var not be the actual chart? i don't get why i need the second var and line var chart = $('#chartDiv').highcharts(); to have an actual chart object. Could be another question all together.. but adding the additional properties and methods to the main highCharts function/class is the question. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: It should be in callback, but what is your goal, what you would like to achieve? Which propetereis you would like to updade / extend?

Comment: as an example, i am capturing the redraw event and i would like the function to know what the user selected time interval is. I am not creating the chart in page, the chart itself is also return from a "class". Right now i am using global vars.. but would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Honestly Im still not sure what is your goal, but if you need get a range on yAxis you can use getExtremes() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes .

Comment: I want exactly what i am saying i want. I want and need to add properties to the chart function. The user is setting the pointInterval through links on the page. I would like to set the value directly in my chart so that the value is available in the redraw event which i define in the "constructor".

Comment: At the beginning, if you ask a question and it is not clear, you should explain, instead of saing "I want excatly what I am saying I want", because it is not helpful. Secondly, I answer you how you can get range. In case when you need to use user's pointInterval, you can set his value as variable, then use this variable in chart configuration.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, what i am asking about is specific. Not sure how else to phrase the question. The variable you are suggesting is what i want to know how to ADD to the chart "class" itself. The HighCharts function returns a chart. I want to add properties to the returned chart and to ALL charts by "extending" through prototype. but i don't know about how this is done because i am learning javascript.

Comment: You can do that only by http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.setOptions . Second solution is using global variable and after chart createion, return updated values and then call xAxis.update() with new pointInterval.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with the `.setOptions()`:
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/how-to-set-options

What options do you want to add?

Comment: my chart is part fake javascript namespace.. so in the page i call the constructor of my chart "class" which returns a chart. Inside the chart i need to be able to set the pointInterval so that the value is available to the redraw event.